# Prevent Qt from generating shortcuts?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a QPushButton as follows, with no explicit shortcut (&):

`testButton = new QPushButton(tr("Start"));`

I can correctly read the button's text just after its construction:

`testButton.text()` returns 'Start' (without single quotes)

Then I create a signal/slot connection:

`QObject::connect(
  testButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
  this, &Dialog::actionRequest
);`

In the `Dialog::actionRequest` slot, `testButton.text()` returns '&Start', as if a shortcut had been created "somewhere", under the hood.

If I name the button 'Foo', the same phenomenon occurs, but `testButton.text()` would return 'F&oo'. That's because I already have a "File" menu, that has an explicit shortcut -- created as:

`fileMenu = new QMenu(tr("&File"), this);`

and, possibly, Alt+O would be the next "available" shortcut?

I do not want this implicit shortcut creation for my QPushButton. What's the solution to this problem? I'm running Fedora 22 ( with plasma 5), with stock qt 5.5 packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it seems to be a "bug" in kde (or at least an "unwanted" feature in my point of view!)

Answer (score 0):

There is a default QShortcut object associated with menu options, buttons, etc. Unfortunately there is no way to directly access and disable them after creation that I know of.

You can attempt to call the Qt global function `qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(false);` to disable this behavior dynamically but I'm not sure if it's available on every platform.